# Include Previous/Next link in each Xaringan slide

Tags: r, xaringan

Since I am embedding a set of slides made with Xaringan on a website, I'm afraid visitors will not understand how to browse the slides.

To make sure everybody will find a way to browse them, I would like to include a previous/next link in the bottom right corner of each slide. It could replace the page numbering, as I don't need the numbering.

I have not been able to find a solution in the documentation or in the online examples I've found.

In the [xaringan wiki there is a page on slide numbers](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/wiki/Slide-number), but it does not clarify how to do this.

Looking at the [remark.js documentation](https://github.com/gnab/remark/wiki/Configuration#general) it seems there is a way to create the numbering through functions, such as this one:

```
  slideNumberFormat: function (current, total) {
    return 'Slide ' + current + ' of ' + total;
  }
```

This looks good, and I should be able to cook a function that makes what I need. However, if I pass the function through nature, e.g.

```
output:   xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      slideNumberFormat: "function (current, total) {return \'Slide \' + current + \' orrrr \' + total;}"
```

this does not seem to work. (it just adds "function..." etc. as text)

I could end up adding manually a div to each slide:

```
<div style="position: absolute; right: 40px; bottom: 10px; width: 300px;">
<h2><a href="#1">Previous</a> / <a href="#3">Next</a></h2>
</div>
```

But this is cumbersome, and I am sure there must be a better way.

**Update**:

As a workaround, I added this block of code in the html *after* I exported it, in this block `<script>var slideshow = remark.create({`:

```
 "slideNumberFormat": function (current, total) {
    return '<h3><a href="#' + (current-1) + '">Previous</a> / <a href="#' + (current+1) + '">Next</a></h3>';
  }
```

Comment: Does your workaround solution work? (It looks like a neat solution by the way!)

Comment: yes, it may need some css customization, but it works. I was also considering using arrow unicode characters  ← / → (instead of "previous/next"), to use less space. So, yes, it works, but it requires manually editing the html after export... so if I find a typo or I want to change something, I have to re-export, and change it again. Also, one must be careful with incremental slides, so it must always be - countIncrementalSlides: true - otherwise it gets the links wrong

Comment: I don't think you need to manually edit html each time. You should be able to save the script in a separate js file and use the YAML as here: https://slides.yihui.name/xaringan/#35